# URLConnection on Android Studio returns less data compared to Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, httpurlconnection

recently I'm trying to grab a Facebook page's source code and work on it. However, I have discovered that the data returned from Intellij IDEA is different from Android Studio where those data is important for further processing.

For example:
[image]

The data on the left side is returned from Intellij IDEA and the right side is returned from Android Studio. You can see there many useful missing on the Android one.
(Maybe you will say indentation problem, but I have searched what I want and it really doesn't exist on the Android one)
May I ask what's happening and the possible solutions? Thank you.

(I am using the exact same code for both sides)

```java
URL facebook = new URL("https://www.facebook.com/Meta");
HttpsURLConnection yc = (HttpsURLConnection) facebook.openConnection();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    // System.out.println(inputLine);
    Log.d("tagg", inputLine);
    lines.add(inputLine);
    // Utils.extractURL(inputLine);
}
in.close();
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="to.epac.factorycraft.notificationtodiscord">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.NotificationToDiscord">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name="to.epac.factorycraft.notificationtodiscord.NotificationService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="NotificationService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You might consider using a more modern HTTP client, such as OkHttp.

Comment: I have tried httpclient and okhttp, the first one act the same as urlhttpconnection and the second one return even less information. Anyone get any ideas?